# How to download a master branch in zip format using python?

Tags: git, python-2.7, zip

I just wanted to write a python code to download a master branch in git in zip format..
How can I do that????

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen('HEAD^')
```

Is it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

For example i download evince pdf viewer from git.gnome.org

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
urlretrieve('https://git.gnome.org/browse/evince/snapshot/evince-3.24.0.zip', 'filename.zip')
```